# VisualSVN and Basic authorization

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server, atlassian-fisheye

This is driving me crazy... I have VisualSVN installed and configured. Now I want to change authentication method to Basic. So, I choose Basic authentication and apply that for the visualSVN server. After that I set the permissions for the repositories for Read/Write to my Windows user, Davor, which name looks like this DEKSTOP-B9QJV3G\Davor. I also set this permission for my Java repository.

The problem is, I can't authenticate to the SVN with this setup. My user, Davor, is the administrator of the machine, it is running Windows 10 and as far as I remember, I never set any passwords for this user.

How can I make this work? I want to make this setup in order to use Atlassian FishEye...

Comment: What's the point in using AD-based authentication on non-domain machine? Do you have a domain? Switch to Subversion auth if you don't have one.

Comment: Unfortunately, FishEye has a bug which prevents me from running VisualSVN Server with Subversion auth. I' dont have a domain.

Comment: could you please describe this bug? Is there an entry on FishEye's bugtracker?

Comment: Yes, this are the bug details: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/FE-4879

Comment: it's about Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA). IWA does not make any sense in non-domain environment (NTLM or Kerberos do not work in workgroups) and it does not ask for credentials. You should clarify the issue since it's totally unclear right now.

Comment: Well, I couldn't use this option because of the bug described in the bugtracker so I had to use the Basic auth and that led me to the original problem in the question. The catch was that i have domain environment, but wanted to test the Basic auth in non-domain environment because I was out of the office. :)

Comment: got it! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use Basic Windows Authentication in non-domain environment, create special [Local Windows Accounts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770642(v=ws.11).aspx) with passwords. These accounts should be used to access VisualSVN Server. VisualSVN Server does not allow empty passwords.

Comment: Thanks, this is working!

Comment: @dplesa you could always contact support@visualsvn.com for assistance, BTW.